# Trying to figure out how to insert the value into an onclick call within a JQuery table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have created a table using JQuery and inserted a button at the end of each row. I set the button up to send the value of the cartridge_ID to the method.  However when I run this the reponse[i].cartridge_ID isn't recognized as defined.

```
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                            debugger;
                            $("#gvCartridges").append("<tr><td>" +
                                response[i].cartridge_ID +
                                "</td><td>" +
                                response[i].cartridge_Number +
                                "</td><td>" +
                                response[i].cartridge_Type +
                                "</td><td>" +
                                response[i].printer_Model +
                                "</td><td><button name='btnIssue' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='issueCartridge(response[i].cartridge_ID)'>Issue</button></td></tr>")

                        };
```

[image: Screen shot of the error]

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It was a question of forgetting how to format the string withing the onclick area of the code.

```
"</td><td><button name='btnIssue' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='issueCartridge(" + response[i].cartridge_ID + ")'>Issue</button></td></tr>"
```